# How to store function as class member variable

Tags: dart

Is it possible in Dart to store a callback function with return and argument type information? It appears I can do the following:

```dart
class MyClass {
  void addCallback( callback( int ) )
  {
    _callback = callback;
  }

  var _callback;
}
```

But I thought it would be nice if `_callback` wasn't declared as `var`, and instead had information about its return and argument types. I couldn't find info on this in the docs, anyone know?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `typedef` a Function signature like this:

```dart
typedef bool Filter(num x);

List<num> filterNumbers(List<num> numbers, Filter filter) {
  return numbers.where(filter).toList();
}
```

For more great information like this, check out this article: https://www.dartlang.org/articles/idiomatic-dart/

Comment: I see, I can use `Filter` as the variable type in my class, very nice.  Though I do think being able to define the typedef within the class would be cleaner, as it wouldn't expose anything to the current namespace (and you'll hardly ever use `Filter` outside of the class anyway, you pass in functions of the same signature).  Thanks!

Comment: You can use libraries to control what you expose.

Answer (score 8):

Dart 2 supports a function type syntax:

```
class MyClass {
  void addCallback( callback( int ) )
  {
    _callback = callback;
  }

  void Function(int) _callback;
}
```

The [Effective Dart Design Guide](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/effective-dart/design#prefer-inline-function-types-over-typedefs) states that this form is preferred over typedefs.